# Symbolic integration of potential over a disc : branch cut problem?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, bugs, symbolic

**Context**

> I am trying to explore the geometry of a crystal made of [irregular bubbles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing).

[image]

See animation [here](https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/best-candidate-circles).

very vaguely in the spirit of [this post](http://yaskebasi.it/archives/2d-unequal-circles-packing) (it is in fact motivated by cosmology and galaxy formation).

So I give myself an interaction potential (which is both attractive and repulsive at large and small distances resp.)

```
pot[r_] = 1/r^2 + r^2
```

looking like this

```
Plot[pot[r], {r, 0.1, 5}]
```

[image]

and I integrate it over a [Disk](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Disk.html)

```
int= Integrate[ pot[Sqrt[(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2]], {x0, y0} ∈ 
  Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]

(* π (x^2+y^2+1/2)  *)
```

which incidentally looks suspicious, because it is lacking a repulsion near the disc.

But if I take a specific value for `{x,y}`

```
rxy = Thread[{x, y} -> {2, 3}]
```

and carry out the integration numerically

```
NIntegrate[
 pot[Sqrt[(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2]] /. rxy, {x0, y0} ∈ 
  Disk[{0, 0}, 1], PrecisionGoal -> 6]

(* 42.663 *)
```

I get a different answer from

```
  int /. rxy 
 
(* 42.4115 *)
```

Indeed if I do the replacement First

```
Integrate[pot[Sqrt[(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2]] /. rxy, {x0, y0} ∈ Disk[{0, 0}, 1]] 

(* π (27/2+log(13/12)) *)

N[%]

(* 42.663 *)
```

So mathematica seems to be doing the general integration wrong.

**Questions**

> Is this a bug? Any workaround?

**Check**

Indeed I can check by integrating numerically radially away from the edge of the disk that the potential generated by the disc is repulsive at close distance:

```
dat = ParallelTable[
  NIntegrate[
   pot[Sqrt[(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2]] /. {x -> r Cos[t], 
      y -> r Sin[t]} /. t -> Pi/4, {x0, y0}∈ 
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1], PrecisionGoal -> 8],
  {r, 1.01, 2, 0.025}];
  dat // ListLinePlot
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, `Integrate` appears to have a problem with the repulsive part; `Integrate[
 1/((x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2), {x0, y0} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 1]]` returns `0` which is obviously wrong. I'd say, this is a bug. Please inform Wolfram Support.

Comment: Maple produces the correct answer $$ 2 \pi \left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\ln\! \left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)}{2}+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{y^{2}}{2}-\frac{\ln\! \left(x^{2}+y^{2}-1\right)}{2}\right)$$ under the assumptions $x\in \mathbb{R},y \in \mathbb{R}, x^2+y^2>1$.

Comment: @user64494 thanks. So this is consistent with the answer given below then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's worth noting that the integrals will evaluate separately!

```
totalPot[x_]=Integrate[(x-x0)^2+(y0)^2,{x0,y0}∈ Disk[{0,0},1]]+
Integrate[1/((x-x0)^2+(y0)^2),{x0,y0}∈ Disk[{0,0},1],Assumptions->{x>1}];
N[totalPot[Sqrt[2^2 + 3^2]]]
(* 42.663 *)
```

The exact form of the potential being

$$\frac{1}{2} \pi  \left(2 r^2-2 \log \left(r^2-1\right)+4 \log (r)+1\right)$$

Where I made sure to use the manifest rotational symmetry to put y=0, and also added an assumption that x is greater than 1 to avoid any issues with divergences in the 1/r^2 case.

Since it's of physical interest, to put units back in, if I take the potential to be an energy density $k_1 r^2+k_2/r^2$ and the disk is of radius $R$, I find:

$$E(r)=k_1 \frac{\pi}{2}(R^4+2 R^2 r^2)-k_2 \pi \log(1-\frac{R^2}{r^2})$$

As noted by Henrik in the comments, this looks like a bug & should be reported to [wolfram support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback).

Comment: thanks! Would you know how to do the integral over an elliptic disc? `int= Integrate[ pot[Sqrt[(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2]], {x0, y0} ∈ 
  Disk[{0, 0}, {1,2}]]`

Comment: @chris hmm I don't. In 3D for the 1/r potential and an ellipsoid I know that the result is pretty complicated with no nice answer. But maybe it's easier here.